# Looking for light-weight Arduino OLED library that supports text and bitmaps

Tags: i2c, library, display

I'm trying to incorporate a screen into my Arduino code which is quite large already. The Adafruit SSD1306 library is overly large and has a lot of unnecessary things in it. I've found the SSD1306Ascii library which is great because it takes up barely any space, but I really would like to be able to display a bitmap logo on the screen. Does anyone know of a library that is light weight but still supports bitmaps?

Thanks.

Comment: Light-weight with bitmaps and your sketch is already large? Then need a newer Arduino board, for example one of the mkr series. Do you know these: https://github.com/olikraus The u8g2 library is large, and the 8x8 option has no bitmaps. The older U8glib is memory efficient but it is still large and it takes time to learn how to use it (because it is memory efficient it has a specific way to update the screen). What is so large about your sketch? Are you a beginner with programming? In the end you need another arduino board anyway, so it is easier to move to a new arduino board right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a small implementation. https://github.com/nicoud/Oled

I have not used it, but it does look interesting. You can pick the bits that you need.

https://www.didel.com/OledLib.pdf